# Is there a way to set an "Interval" or "Tick" on a Slider in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, maui

Im trying to create a Slider that snaps only on whole numbers (0 - 100).
I dont see any Property like "Interval" or "Tick" am i blind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in a `Slider` .NET MAUI control by handling the data in the code behind it.

The first thing you need to add is a `Slider` object with the `ValueChanged` event handler.

To do so with XAML:

```
<Slider
    Minimum="0"
    Maximum="100"
    ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged" />
```

To do the same with C#:

```
Slider slider = new()
    {
        Maximum = 100, // It is important to set the maximum value first.
        Minimum = 0
    };
```

Now, you need the method that will run when the `ValueChanged` event is fired. This is where our logic will happen.

```
// The value we want the slider to increment each time it updates
readonly double sliderIncrement = 5;

// The value for the slider we will be using.
double sliderCorrectValue;

// The actual method. If the Slider object was instantiated in C#, read below.
private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Recognize the sender as a Slider object.
    Slider slider = (Slider)sender;

    // Get the slider value relative to the minimum,
    // needed to calculate valid values with increment.
    double relativeValue = slider.Value - slider.Minimum;

    // Check if the value is valid, based on our increment.
    if(relativeValue % sliderIncrement == 0)
    {
        // Value is valid
        sliderCorrectValue = slider.Value;

        // Update label text (optional)
        valueDisplayer.Text = sliderCorrectValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

This essentially creates a `sliderCorrectValue` `double` that stores our `Slider`'s value if it is valid. Note that you need to use the `sliderCorrectValue` as your result value since the built-in `Value` `Property` of the `Slider` can still be an unwanted value.

If you created the Slider in C#, use this to handle the `ValueChanged` event.

```
slider.ValueChanged += (sender, e) =>
    {
        // The same code as above
    };
```

However, I personally recommend always using XAML instead of C# when building the user interface for .NET MAUI apps.

Comment: @DavidJazbec Always accept answers for people with similar problems (if you think the answer is good, of course).